# Get-SPGroup and Set-SPGroup commands

Tags: 2013, powershell, groups

Like `Get-SPUser` and `Set-SPUser`, are there any commands like `Get-SPGroup` and `Set-SPGroup` ? I want to use Powershell commands like

```
Set-SPGroup -Identity $ADGroupName -Web $SiteCollection
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to look at [PNP SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps) commands. It may help accomplish what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such OOTB function available. But you can write your own custom commands.

Quick Bing points me the three custom commands, Check these if that solve your issues.

1. [Remove-SPGroup](http://sharepointryan.com/2011/07/21/remove-sharepoint-groups-using-powershell-2/)
2. [New-SPGroup](http://sharepointryan.com/2011/07/20/create-sharepoint-groups-using-powershell/)
3. [Get-SPGroup](http://sharepointryan.com/2011/07/18/retrieve-sharepoint-groups-using-powershell/)